# How to customize context menu in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, contextmenu, customization

Is it possible to customize context menu in Visual Studio Code ?

Currently it looks like this.

[image]

I need to add two more menu options to this.

Something like "Go Back" and "Go Forward".

Can this be done ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use these commands from "command palette"? `ctrl+shift+p` or `F1` => and type command

Comment: You can customize it if you are [writing an extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesmenus), not sure if there's another way

Comment: Yes I wrote an extension. Here it is. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamAnand.adamstool

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can can add menu items to the context menu by creating a personal extension for your own use.  In your extension, in `package.json`, add a [`contributes.menus`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus) section.  The text editor context menu is called `editor/context`.

(If you haven't developed an extension before, start with Microsoft's [Your First Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) tutorial.)

It may help to look at another extension that adds items to the context menu.  One (of many) extension that does this is [Bookmarks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.Bookmarks), which adds three context menu entries.  The relevant parts of its [`package.json`](https://github.com/alefragnani/vscode-bookmarks/blob/master/package.json) are:

```json
{
    "name": "Bookmarks",
    ...
    "contributes": {
        ...
        "menus": {
            ...
            "editor/context": [
                {
                    "command": "bookmarks.toggle",
                    "group": "bookmarks",
                    "when": "editorTextFocus && config.bookmarks.showCommandsInContextMenu"
                },
                {
                    "command": "bookmarks.jumpToNext",
                    "group": "bookmarks@1",
                    "when": "editorTextFocus && config.bookmarks.showCommandsInContextMenu"
                },
                {
                    "command": "bookmarks.jumpToPrevious",
                    "group": "bookmarks@1",
                    "when": "editorTextFocus && config.bookmarks.showCommandsInContextMenu"
                }
            ],
            ....
        },
        ....
    },
    ....
}
```

The `command` can be any command; it does not have to be one installed by your extension.

The [API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus) are a bit vague about the meaning of the `group` attribute:

> Last, a `group` property defines sorting and grouping of menu items.

Its meaning is described more fully under [Sorting of groups](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#Sorting-of-groups).  A word like "bookmarks" establishes a group of menu entries separated from other groups by a horizontal rule, with groups ordered alphabetically, and the "@<number>" suffix controls ordering within each group:

[image: Screenshot of three added context menu items]

Comment: In case people are wondering, you can also add commands that aren't defined by your own extension, e.g., I have a personal extension, and I was able to add a menu item for the built-in `editor.action.transformToTitlecase` command so I can make text title case by right-clicking it.

Comment: This doesnt answer the question. Is your answer suggesting us to install the "bookmarks" extension and go to settings.json to configure it to our own command?

Comment: @zhuhang.jasper My answer is suggesting to write a personal extension in order to add menu items.  Bookmarks is just an illustrative example to follow.  I've edited the answer to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 0):

As for solutions that don't require installing an extension, this is tracked by a feature-request issue ticket: [User configurable menus #9285](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/106483), which apparently is supposed to support adding and removing entries from context menus. You can show your support for the feature-request by giving it a thumbs up, and you can subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like "+1" / "bump". If you want to contribute to design discussion there, please keep it constructive.

---

You can *add* context menu items by writing an extension. I don't think extensions can *remove* context menu items that were contributed by another extension.

You'd need to implement a menu contribution. You can find related docs at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus. In your extension manifest (package.json), fill in the appropriate config in `contributes` > `menus`. The screenshot you've shown is of the `editor/context` menu. You register the menu item contribution with a corresponding command that clicking the menu item will call, and then you implement the command in the same way you'd implement any other command contribution (see also https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.commands).

If you want to see an example of an extension that contributes a menu, see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/source-control-sample.