# VS Code: How to make the multi-line comment as Right Click menu item?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using the latest Visual Studio Code, how can I make the below combination key

**Shift** + **Alt** + **A**

so that it can appear as right-click menu function?

Comment: If the question is asking how to add an entry to the context menu, then it is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714353/how-to-customize-context-menu-in-visual-studio-code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to bring up the editor context menu there is a keybinding for that:

```
{
  "key": "shift+f10",
  "command": "editor.action.showContextMenu",
  "when": "textInputFocus"
}
```

So you could change that to your chosen keybinding which I note is already bound to `editor.action.blockComment` so you will lose the block comment toggle ability if you use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>.

Also that command only brings up the editor context menu, even if your explorer has focus for instance - which have a different context menu.  There doesn't appear to be any command for bringing up whichever context menu is contextual given current focus - only the editor context menu which may be what you want anyhow?

Comment: Would it be possible to put one more entry in the Context Menu option called Block Comment instead?

Comment: Not without an extension as @Scott pointed out - it would be very interesting if someone could write an extension that read a specified array of commands from user/workplace settings to create a custom context menu!