# VSCode - copy localhost path in right-click menu

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to add a custom item to the right-click menu in the VSCode explorer?

Specifically, I am looking to add a "Copy Localhost Path" type of option, where it just takes the "Copy Relative path" option (`relative/path/to/file.html`) and put my localhost before it (`http://localhost:8000/relative/path/to/file.html`)

I'm just tired of navigating to localhost:8000 and pasting the relative path after it.

[image: right click menu]

Thanks

Comment: you can add a new menu entry to the context menu of the explorer

Comment: @rioV8  is there a way to do it without creating an entire extension?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714353/how-to-customize-context-menu-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written an extension ([Context Menu Extra](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.context-menu-extra)) that adds this command to the context menus of the explorer and the editor.

You can also call the command from the command palette and add a key binding to use the current file.

You can also set the port number to use and a possible web root directory in case the webserver does not serve from the workspace root folder.