# how to remove items from right click context menu in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, contextmenu, right-click

Currently, my right click context menu looks like this

[image]

It is too long. Many items I don't ever use. Can I remove some items from the menu?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize context menu in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714353/how-to-customize-context-menu-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: My right-click context menu has got shorter after I reinstalled VSCode

Comment: did you update VS Code? if so, from what version to what version? or did you uninstall any extensions that contributed items to the context menu?

Comment: I think this question is unique. starball's suggestion applies to *adding* to the context menu.

Answer (score -3):

You can click the menu bar then by right click you will get the option to close the component.

Comment: I don't why I can not see the option to close the component in my menu bar. Can you post an image?

Comment: The question is about the Context Menu, not the Menu Bar.