# How to remove unnecessary menu items from VS Code's context menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to remove unnecessary menu items.

For example, in the images below, red means remove, white means do not touch:

[image]

Comment: related for _adding_ items: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46714353/11107541, but I don't think it covers _removing_, so not a dup of that.

Comment: Yeah, it's a different way to do it here.

Comment: actually, I've changed my mind. I'd rather use that question to cover both additions and removals, and I've added an answer that covers both (though not in the most satisfactory way).

Comment: No it doesn't, I don't understand how to remove inbuilt and added by other people's extensions menu items.

Comment: my answer there says: it's a pending feature request. all you can do is wait. unless you want to be the one to make it a reality.

Comment: Well, then I'm waiting for someone to do it.

Comment: please either fix your title or clarify your screenshot. your title says "command palette", but what you show in your screenshot is a context menu- not the command palette. also, please allow this question to be closed as a duplicate now that I've answered the question.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer my question, it writes how to add items but not how to remove.

Comment: this is the second time I'm telling you (and you already acknowledged this) that the answer is that you _can't_, and if you want to be able to, you need to upvote a feature request and wait for it to get implemented or implement it yourself.

Comment: When this functionality is available, then I'll close it.
Why close an issue when there is no solution?

Comment: [/help/duplicates](/help/duplicates)

Comment: It's not duplicate, it's issue without solution.

Answer (score -2):

Open VS-Code then click on the tools menu and find the customize option

In the customize section hit the commands tab.
In the commands tab, hit the context menu option then in the context menu option, hit the editor context menus / code window option.

Once there select the menu item that you want to remove and hit the delete button.

After that restart VS Code and you should be good to go

Comment: I can't find edit option. https://ibb.co/m09hmwT

Comment: what is this "customize option" you are talking about?

Comment: @starball
 Commands tab = CRTL + SHIFT + P

Comment: that's called the "command palette".

Comment: there is no **Tools** menu in VSC, there is in VS