# Collapse VS Code explorer subfolders of a specified folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm struggling to find the files I want to work on in my project, do you know how to collapse all subfolders from a parent folder in the VS Code explorer section using commands?

I know that you can achieve this using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>
but this collapses all folders, I want to collapse only the subfolders by selecting the parent folder

Before using command:

```
parent folder
  | subfolder
  |  |  file
  | subfolder
  |  |  file
```

After using the command:

```
parent folder
  | subfolder
  | subfolder
```

Comment: I am on Mac, arrow right expends and arrow left collapses only parent folder. No cmd is pressed

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a combination of the command `list.collapseAllToFocus` and `listExpand`. Ex. (in keybindings.json, which you can open using the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette))

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "list.collapseAllToFocus",
            "list.expand",
        ],
    },
    "when": "listFocus",
},
```

Move focus/selection to the list item you want to collapse all the children of, and then invoke the keybinding.

I'm not aware of a way to do this via context menu. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77385463/11107541.